# Excluir (renomear) figuras em PHP com AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, font-awesome

Tenho uma página (up.php) que mostra o seguinte:

[image: up.php]

Quero fazer o seguinte, ao clicar em Apagar em qualquer uma delas, apareça um fa-cog centralizado na imagem e depois remova ela dali.

O que tenho até agora faz o serviço, mas visualmente é ruim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.meio {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<?php
$path = "img/";
$diretorio = dir($path);

while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()) {
    if (substr($arquivo, 0, 6) == 'modelo' ) {
        $fotoscaminhocompleto[] = $path.$arquivo; 
        $nomearquivo[] = pathinfo($arquivo, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extarquivo[] = pathinfo($arquivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    }
}
$diretorio -> close();

echo '<form method="post" id="apagarfoto" action="#">'; 
for ($x=0;$x<count($nomearquivo);$x++) {    
    echo '<div style="float: left; padding:5px;" align="center" id="'.$nomearquivo[$x].'">';
    echo $nomearquivo[$x].'<br />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="apagar" value="'.$nomearquivo[$x].'.'.$extarquivo[$x].'" />';
    echo '<img src="'.$path.'/'.$nomearquivo[$x].'.'.$extarquivo[$x].'" width="100px" /><br />';
    ?><button type="submit" onclick="myAjax('<?php echo $nomearquivo[$x]; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Apagar</button><br /><?php
    echo '</div>';
}
echo '</form>';
?>
<script>
function myAjax(nome) {
    var nomediv = nome;
    $('#apagarfoto').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var serializeDados = $('#apagarfoto').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "foto_apagar.php",
            dataType: "html",
            data: serializeDados,       
            beforeSend: function() {
                document.getElementById(nomediv).innerHTML = '<div align="center"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-cog fa-3x"></i></div>';
            },
            complete: function() {
                document.getElementById(nomediv).innerHTML = "";
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus) {

            },
            error: function(xhr, er) {
                $("#resposta").html("Erro!");
            }
      });
    });
};
</script>
```

E a página em PHP que executa a "exclusão" (na verdade renomeia) é a seguinte:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
ini_set(“display_errors”, 0 );
$base_dir = 'img/';
$retorno = rename($base_dir.$_POST['apagar'], $base_dir.'renomeado_'.$_POST['apagar']);
//sleep(3);
/*
if ($retorno == 1) {
    header("location: up.php");
} else {
    echo 'Nao foi possivel executar a operacao. Entre em contato com o webmaster da pagina.';
}
*/
?>
```

Sei que tá meio confuso mas o que pretendo é o seguinte: Procurar na pasta "img" as figuras que começam com o nome "modelo" e exibi-las para o usuário apagá-las se quiser. O usuário vai achar que apagou mas elas permanecerão na pasta, apenas serão renomeadas e não aparecerão mais.

Precisando de alguma complementação estou à disposição!

Obrigado antecipadamente!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que você está fazendo da forma errada. Ao clicar no botão você está disparando dois eventos ao mesmo tempo, o de click e o de submit.

Não precisa usar essa função `myAjax()`, você pode usar a função do evento. Primeira coisa é remover o `onclick` do botão e alterar o type para `button`. Esse botão não tem a função de submeter o formulário, mas apenas a função de um botão normal. Então ficaria apenas assim:

```
<button type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Apagar</button>
```

Agora você cria um evento para os botões. Quando um for clicado, irá pegar o id da div pai e disparar o submit enviando a id para o outro evento como parâmetro:

```
$("#apagarfoto button").on("click", function(e){
   var nomediv = $(e.target).closest("div").attr("id");
   $('#apagarfoto').trigger("submit", nomediv);
});
```

O outro evento, de submit, você acrescenta mais um parâmetro `nomediv` na função e remove a linha `var nomediv = nome;`, porque a variável `nomediv` já vem na função. Ficará assim:

```
$('#apagarfoto').submit(function(e, nomediv) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var serializeDados = $('#apagarfoto').serialize();

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "foto_apagar.php",
      dataType: "html",
      data: serializeDados,       
      beforeSend: function() {
          document.getElementById(nomediv).innerHTML = '<div align="center"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-cog fa-3x"></i></div>';
      },
      complete: function() {
          document.getElementById(nomediv).innerHTML = "";
      },
      success: function (data, textStatus) {

      },
      error: function(xhr, er) {
          $("#resposta").html("Erro!");
      }
});
});
```

**Testando:**

No exemplo abaixo coloquei um setTimeout no `complete:` apenas para dar um delay e ilustrar o funcionamento (copie o código que coloquei mais acima ):

```js
$("#apagarfoto button").on("click", function(e){
   var nomediv = $(e.target).closest("div").attr("id");
   $('#apagarfoto').trigger("submit", nomediv);
});

$('#apagarfoto').submit(function(e, nomediv) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var serializeDados = $('#apagarfoto').serialize();

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "foto_apagar.php",
      dataType: "html",
      data: serializeDados,       
      beforeSend: function() {
          document.getElementById(nomediv).innerHTML = '<div align="center"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-cog fa-3x"></i></div>';
      },
      complete: function() {
         setTimeout(function(){  // apenas exemplo
          document.getElementById(nomediv).innerHTML = "";
         }, 3000); // apenas exemplo
      },
      success: function (data, textStatus) {

      },
      error: function(xhr, er) {
          $("#resposta").html("Erro!");
      }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form method="post" id="apagarfoto" action="#">
<div style="float: left; padding:5px;" align="center" id="arquivo0">
   arquivo 0<br />
   <input type="hidden" name="apagar" value="arquivo0texto0" />
   <img src="" width="100px" /><br />
   <button type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Apagar</button><br />
</div>
<div style="float: left; padding:5px;" align="center" id="arquivo1">
   arquivo 1<br />
   <input type="hidden" name="apagar" value="arquivo1texto1" />
   <img src="" width="100px" /><br />
   <button type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Apagar</button><br />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Simplesmente perfeito! Eu não manjo muito de javascript e ajax, mas já deu uma boa ideia do que pode ser feito! Muitíssimo obrigado!